# Как добавить столбец образованный с помощью groupby и aggregate в датафрейм?

Tags: pandas, group-by

Имеется датафрейм
[image]

делаю группировку по Сoach c агрегацией по среднему Weight
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как теперь создать новый столбец в датасете со средним значением Weight?

**df['Avg Weight per Coach'] = df.groupby(['Coach']).aggregate({'Weight':'mean'})** создает столбец но все значения в нем Nan. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте ***transform***

```
df['Avg Weight per Coach'] = df.groupby('Coach')['Weight'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Comment: *Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.*